# How do I access Kaminari's path_to_next_page method in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, kaminari

I need to access Kaminari's path_to_next_page method in my controller, how can this be done?
I've tried this to include in controller `include Kaminari::Helpers::UrlHelper` works fine on development server, but on heroku it crashes the app... Any ideas?

Heroku log: https://gist.github.com/zilton7/cf1ee417b07fae3d0960be2af6d80624

Gemfile: https://gist.github.com/zilton7/3a5e19b602979c0b806e37b1937d266e

Comment: Try including `Kaminari::Helpers::HelperMethods`,  https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/kaminari-core/1.0.1/Kaminari%2FHelpers%2FHelperMethods:path_to_next_page

Comment: I have tried it first actually, didn't work

Comment: I started having the same issue after upgrading from Rails 6.0 to Rails 6.1.